# Web deploy "works" but some files not served

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have VS 2015 and a smallish C# web app.  I can debug it on my desktop without issue.  I have setup Web Deploy and have deployed the app to a dev server.  The puzzling thing is that there are a couple of files that exist on the dev site that are not being served by the IIS server.

In my app I created a "LocalContent" folder at the same level as Views, Models, Scripts, etc with this structure

```
.../LocalContent/css
.../LocalContent/css/index.css
.../LocalContent/js
.../LocalContent/js/index.js
```

I can see the `BuildAction` property for the index.{css,js} files is set to `Content` and they do exist on the dev server.

When I load the dev site these resources both throw 403 errors (as seen through Chrome's Dev Tools).  Not only that, looking at the URIs to these resources does not, for example, give `.../LocalContent/css/index.css`.  Instead the dev-tools networking display shows something more like: `.../LocalContent/css/?v=<long string of garble>`.

This is my first IIS deployment so I am not sure what is or should be going on.  Do I need to do something terribly Microsofty after each Publish event and restart the IIS process or reboot the IIS server machine?

Comment: What is the actual URL of the content? Is the `LocalContent` folder in the root of your app? Oh, and by the way, the `?v=xxxx` is called cache busting.

Comment: Yes, `LocalContent` is in the root of the project.  The desired url would be: `http://my.site.com/LocalContent/css/index.css`

Comment: And what do you get if you put that URL in the browser?

Comment: the content of the css file

Comment: And with the query string?

Answer (score 1):

These files are likely being served by IIS's static file handler, which acts as a different identity to your application pool.

Assuming your server is configured with defaults, granting the `IUSR` user access to your web root (or at least the specific directory)\ that contain the static files) should solve your problem.

Comment: So why does the content of the CSS file show when requesting it directly?

Comment: Existing ACLs, uncommon configuration, css being handled by your application layer, who knows.